# Can't get bibliography to change style

Tags: bibliographies, citing, apa-style

I'm trying the change the bibliography style in my document from `IEEEtran` to `apa`. I've made a dummy doc with the same preamble as my full doc, and using the same `bib` file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, left=2cm, top = 2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage[symbol]{footnotemisc}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{dcolumn,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}

\let\oldFootnote\footnote
\newcommand\nextToken\relax

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}} 
\renewcommand\footnote[1]{%
    \oldFootnote{#1}\futurelet\nextToken\isFootnote}

\newcommand\isFootnote{%
    \ifx\footnote\nextToken\textsuperscript{,}\fi}

\captionsetup{font={normalfont},labelfont=footnotesize, width=.6\textwidth}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\newcommand\cjaa{Chinese Journal of Astronomy \& Astrophysics}
\newcommand\pasp{Astronomical Society of the Pacific, Publications}
\newcommand\apj{The Astrophysical Journal}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\singlespacing
%\onehalfspacing
\doublespacing
%\setstretch{1.1}

\begin{document}
Hello world \cite{chj+17}

\bibliography{QSO_bibliography3}
%\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliographystyle{apa}
\end{document}
```

The commented-out `\bibliographystyle` works fine to produce the following output:

[image]

but when I run the `apa` command below it, the style doesn't change. I need the citations to look like the ones [in this document](https://www.mackichan.com/products/shells/apa.pdf). I compile the doc 4 times like it says in Step 5 [here](https://www.reed.edu/cis/help/LaTeX/bibtexstyles.html#top) but it still doesn't change. The contents of my `bib` file look like

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@preamble{"
   \providecommand{\pasp}{Publications of the Astronomical Society of the Pacific}
   \providecommand{\cjaa}{Chinese Journal of Astronomy~\& Astrophysics}
   \providecommand{\mnras}{Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society}
   \providecommand{\apjl}{Astrophysical Journal Letters}
   \providecommand{\ssr}{Space Science Reviews}
   \providecommand{\aap}{Astronomy and Astrophysics}
   \providecommand{\apjs}{Astrophysical Journal Supplement}
   \providecommand{\rmxaa}{Revista Mexicana de Astronom\'{i}a y Astrof\'{i}sica}
   \providecommand{\aj}{Astrophysical Journal}
"}

@ARTICLE{chj+17,
   author = {Curran, S. J. and Hunstead, R. W. and Johnston, H. M. and 
             Whiting, M. T. and Sadler, E.~M. and Allison, J.~R. and 
             Bignell, C.},
    title = "Further Observational Evidence for a Critical Ionising 
             Luminosity in Active Galaxies",
  journal = {ArXiv e-prints},
archivePrefix = "arXiv",
   eprint = {1706.06508},
 keywords = {Astrophysics - Astrophysics of Galaxies},
     year = 2017,
    month = jun,
      url = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2017arXiv170606508C},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
%plus others
```

I've tried downloading and extracting `bst` files from [here](https://www.mackichan.com/index.html?techtalk/632.htm~mainFrame) but to no avail. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: loading `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}` rather than `\usepackage{cite}` and calling as `\citet{chj+17}` results in:

[image]

Do I need to change the contents of the `bib` file too?

Comment: The screenshot that accompanies your follow-up query would appear to indicate that you didn't perform a full recompile cycle (latex-bibtex-latex-latex) after changing the argument of `\bibliographystyle` from `IEEEtran` to `apa`. What makes me thinks this, you may ask? For one, the `apa` bibliography style is **ancient** and doesn't know what to with (and hence simply ignores) the `url` field. However, the formatted bibliography still shows the contents of the entry's `url` field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently loading the `cite` citation management package. It can produce only numeric-style citation call-outs, i.e., `[1]`, `[2]`, etc.

Employing the `cite` citation management package is fine for the `IEEEtran` bibliography style, which is designed to create numeric-style citation call-outs. Using `cite` is *not ok* along with the `apa` bibliography style, though, as that style is meant to create authoryear-style, not numeric-stye, citation call-outs.

What to do? Answer: Don't load the `cite` package. Instead, I recommend you load the `natbib` citation management package, preferably with the option `authoryear`:

```
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apa}
```

Happy BibTeXing!

Comment: Your comment was a step in the right direction, but not quite there; see the edit in the question.

Comment: @Jim421616 - Did you remember (or know) that it’s necessary to re-run LaTeX *twice* after running BibTeX? The first LaTeX run updates the items in the formatted bibliography, and the second updates the citation call-outs. So, if you haven’t already done so, please rerun LaTeX on your document one more time.

Comment: By “re-run LaTeX”, do you mean just compile the document? I compiled it a number of times (>2). Or do I need to change some setting between compiles? Sorry for the noob questions.

Comment: @Jim421616 - Did you also rerun BibTeX after changing the argument of `\bibliographystyle` — to `apa`, right? Assuming the arguments of `\bibliography` (one or more bib files) and of `\bibliography` are correct and free of syntactic errors, running LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more should resolve all citation call-outs.